# Validate checkbox group with data annotations / unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have a model that has a group of checkboxes. I want to have a validation that fails unless at least one of the checkboxes is checked.

When I wrote the original model, I had each checkbox as a separate boolean:

```
    [DataMember]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ResourceData), Name = "Monday")]        
    public bool Monday { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ResourceData), Name = "Tuesday")]
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ResourceData), Name = "Wednesday")]
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ResourceData), Name = "Thursday")]
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ResourceData), Name = "Friday")]
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
```

What would be the best way to design the model with a custom validation class that will also work with unobtrusive validation?

Would it be better to somehow create a custom class for each checkbox and have a collection of those on my model with some data annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start for you: [Link](http://www.jasonlinham.co.uk/2012/03/mvc-checkbox-validation-with-data.html). You just to create your own custom Data Annotation and add it just as the link suggests.  Now, regarding your questions, I believe the best course of action would be to use a collection of checkboxes and adding the annotation to that collection, and then checking if at least one is checked as the link does it.

Hope this helps!